# Dynamic url issue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have project structured in 2 parts: frontend urls and backend urls. The backend urls are like `base-url/admin/pagename` the frontend urls are like `base-url/pagename`.

I want to create some dynamic pages. The url name are came from the database.

this is my route from the `web.php` file:

```
Route::any('{slug}', 'PageController@show');
```

This is my controller

```
public function show($slug = null)
{
   if('admin' != $slug){
      $page = Pages::where('route', $slug)->where('active', 1);
      $page = $page->firstOrFail();
      return view($page->template)->with('page', $page);
   }
}
```

Somehow I want to avoid to take into consideration every url starting with `baseurl/admin/`. I am wondering if I can do it from the `web.php`. If yes , how ?

Answer (score 0):

Define all your static routes first for precedence issues. Then define your any route at the end, with some regular expressions

```
Route::any('{slug}', 'PageController@show')->where('slug', '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$');
```

This is telling the url to only allow alphanumeric and dashes `-`. So any url with a forward slash wont work.

```
/my-first-page-1 --> should work
/my/first/page/2 --> shouldn't work
```

this way you know `baseurl/admin/` will never work. You can search online for more regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Route::any('/base-url/admin/{slug}', 'SomeController@someMethod');

Route::any('{slug}', 'PageController@show');
```

laravel routes are matched from top to bottom and it will stop when it finds the first match, so routes defined first take precedence over those defined later, in this case, the first route will match any request for url starting with `/base-url/admin/` and the second route will match everything else.

you just need to replace `'SomeController@someMethod'` with the controller in charge of that functionality